# getting inputstream canot be null for wso2 data service

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I am using wso2 esb 4.0.3 and created a wso2 data service which is calling a teradata procedure by passing two input parameters and getting 16 columns as response.

Sometimes it's giving the proper output but somtimes it's giving an error:

How can I can get constant response?

```
    [2013-06-10 15:18:54,097]  INFO - HTTPSender Unable to sendViaPost to url[http://localhost:8280/services/SampleSemsDataService1.SOAP12Endpoint]
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: InputStream cannot be NULL.
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender.processResponse(AbstractHTTPSender.java:219)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.handleResponse(HTTPSender.java:271)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:194)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:75)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:449)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:276)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:406)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.sendReceive(ServiceClient.java:555)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.sendReceive(ServiceClient.java:531)
    at org.apache.jsp.admin.jsp.WSRequestXSSproxy_005fajaxprocessor_jsp._jspService(WSRequestXSSproxy_005fajaxprocessor_jsp.java:272)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:332)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:161)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(ServletRegistration.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:67)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bridge.BridgeServlet.service(BridgeServlet.java:164)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:154)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.TomcatServer$1.invoke(TomcatServer.java:254)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProcessor.process(Http11NioProcessor.java:396)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:356)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1534)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
[2013-06-10 15:19:02,764]  WARN - HttpCoreNIOSender Connection closed by client : 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 HTTPSender Unable to sendViaPost to url[http://localhost:8280/services/SampleSemsDataService1.SOAP12Endpoint]
```

Your data service runs on port 8280? Did you install DS feature in ESB? if so, you should use servlet transport (port 9763/9443)not the NIO transport

Comment: Yes,I have added Data-service3.2.3 feature in esb.As you suggest, i think there is change required in axi2.xml present in esb. Can you please give more clarity on how  i can use servle-transport ports instead of  NIO transport.

Comment: I am using wso2-esb 4.0.3 with data-service 3.2.3 feature installed in it.I checked your's link and found the similar doc for wso2-esb 4.0.3.Now the problem is,wso2 esb-4.0.3 doesnot have any transports.xml . I found one /Users/saurabh/Desktop/wso2esb-4.0.3/repository/conf/mgt-transports.xml. and it's containing the following.<transport name="http" class="org.wso2.carbon.server.transports.http.HttpTransport">
                <parameter name="protocol">HTTP_11_NIO</parameter>
           <parameter name="port">${Ports.ServletTransports.HTTP}</parameter>.

Comment: I am using wso2-esb 4.0.3 with data-service 3.2.3 feature installed in it.I checked your's link and found the similar doc for wso2-esb 4.0.3.Now the problem is,wso2 esb-4.0.3 doesnot have any transports.xml . I found one /Users/saurabh/Desktop/wso2esb-4.0.3/repository/conf/mgt-transports.xml. and it's containing the following.<transport name="http" class="org.wso2.carbon.server.transports.http.HttpTransport">
                <parameter name="protocol">HTTP_11_NIO</parameter>
        <parameter name="port">${Ports.ServletTransports.HTTP}</parameter>. Haven't got clear picture .Please suggest.

Comment: Followed the following link: